# How to save the sort order in Dataframe?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a new column to save the sort order, which is sorted by one of the columns, in Dataframe. For example, I would like to sort by column 'B'(ascending) and add a new column 'C' to save the sort order. that means i want to get a column'C', which is [4,3,1,2,4,2]

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"B":[5,2,0,1,5,1]})
```

Comment: the sort order does not need to be saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [rank](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html?highlight=rank#pandas.DataFrame.rank), and `method='dense'` so that rank always increases by 1 between groups:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"B":[5,2,0,1,5,1]})
df['C']=df['B'].rank(method='dense')
df
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   5   4
1   2   2   3
2   3   0   1
3   4   1   2
4   5   5   4
5   6   1   2
```